Difference between the expectation value of an operator and operator applied to wave function?
Expectation value of any operator $\hat{Q}$ is defined as,
$$
\left\langle\psi_n\mid\hat{Q}\mid \psi_n\right\rangle
$$
and action of the operator $\hat{Q}$ on wavefunction is defined as
$$
\hat{Q} \mid\psi_n\rangle= q \mid\psi_n\rangle
$$
It is my understanding, that when we apply an operator (say $\hat{H}$) to a wavefunction it returns its eigenvalue corresponding to the wavefunction, which would be $E_n$ in this case, but isn't that just the same as $\left\langle\psi_n\mid\hat{H}\mid \psi_n\right\rangle $ ?
I'd like to know what the difference is between
$\hat{Q}\mid\psi_n\rangle$ and $\left\langle\psi_n\mid\hat{Q}\mid \psi_n\right\rangle$, what exactly are you doing when you apply an operator to a wavefunction?

For eigenstates, the expectation is the eigenvalue. But for superpositions of eigenstates, the expectation weights eigenvalues with probabilities.

The expectation value is a number. The left and right sides of the eigenequation are functions.

why are there close votes? This is kind of a tricky part of beginner QM, and sort of lead into the measurement problem which still generates lots of interpretation conversation.

Do you know linear algebra? It might be worth to take a step back from the physics and just consider the math. Then the difference between both things should be clear.


Specifically, I'd like to know what the difference is between
$\hat{Q} \psi_n$ and $\left\langle\psi_n\mid\hat{Q}\mid \psi_n\right\rangle$

Your
$\hat Q|\psi_n\rangle $ represents an operator $\hat Q$ acting on a state $|\psi_n\rangle$, which will result in another state, e.g., $|\chi_n\rangle$ a la:
$$
|\chi_n\rangle = \hat Q |\psi_n\rangle\;.
$$
In the case where the state $|\psi_n\rangle$ is an eigenstate of the operator $\hat Q$, the state $|\chi_n\rangle$ is proportional to the state $|\psi_n\rangle$ and we can write:
$$
\hat Q|\psi_n\rangle = q|\psi_n\rangle\;,
$$
where $q$ is a number.

An expectation value has it's usual meaning from probability theory. Given a function $q(\vec x)$ and a probability density $p(\vec x)$, the expectation value is:
$$
E_p[Q] = \int d x p(\vec x)q(\vec x)\;.
$$
Or, if it is easier to think about in terms of discrete probabilities $p_i$, the expectation value is a sum:
$$
E_p[Q] = \sum_i p_i q_i\;.
$$

In quantum mechanics, the probability density is related to the state via
$$
p_n(\vec x) = |\psi_n(\vec x)|^2\;,
$$
where we are now thinking of the state $|\psi_n\rangle$ in a basis, such as for example the position $\vec x$ basis, such that $\psi_n(\vec x) = \langle \vec x | \psi_n\rangle$.
If an operator like $\hat Q$ is diagonal in the position basis, we can write:
$$
\hat Q = \int d x |\vec x\rangle\langle\vec x |q(\vec x)\;,
$$
where $q(\vec x)$ is a function (not an operator).
Then, we can write:
$$
\langle \psi_n|\hat Q |\psi_n\rangle = \int d x \psi_n(\vec x)^* q(\vec x)\psi_n(\vec x)
$$
$$
=\int d x |\psi_n(\vec x)|^2 q(\vec x)
$$
$$
=\int d x p_n(\vec x) q(\vec x)
$$
$$
=E_{p_n}[Q]
$$


I do not understand how the expectation value relates to eigen function equations:
$$
\hat{Q} \mid\psi_n\rangle= q \mid\psi_n\rangle\;.\tag{A}
$$

The above Eq. (A) is only true (by definition) when the state $|\psi_n\rangle$ is a eigenstate of the operator $\hat Q$. The eigenvalue is called $q$, and it is generally a complex number (or a real number if the operator is Hermitian).
If such a equation is true, this is the same as saying that the state has a definite value $q$ for the operator $\hat Q$. If the operator $\hat Q$ is a Hermitian "observable" (which thus has real eigenvalues and can correspond to real measurements) then we say that the measure value will be $q$ with 100% probability. This also means that the expected value (expectation value) will be $q$, which is trivial to see, since we assume the state is normalized:
$$
\langle \psi_n|\hat Q|\psi_n\rangle = q\langle\psi_n|\psi_n\rangle =q\;,
$$
where the first equality follow from Eq. (A).
However, in general, there is no reason to expect that Eq. (A) will hold for arbitrary states and operators. In a discrete basis, we would rather expect that generally:
$$
\hat Q |\psi_n\rangle = \sum_{m}|\psi_m\rangle Q_{m,n}\;. \tag{B}
$$
Eq. (A) is a special case of Eq. (B) when only one term in the sum contributes (the term with $m=n$, which we called $q=Q_{n,n}$).

Thanks for your answer, my question has been edited, hopefully it is clearer

The expectation value of an observable $\hat{Q}$ is the average obtained by repeated measurements of $\hat{Q}$ (i.e., average of the eigenvalues of $\hat{Q}$). That is, it is the most likely outcome of a measurement of the observable $\hat Q$. Hence the word expectation (value).

But I do not understand how the expectation value relates to eigen function equations:
$$
\hat{Q} \mid\psi_n\rangle= q \mid\psi_n\rangle
$$

This equation states that a measurement of the physical observable $\hat Q$ gives us the value $q$ where $q$ is the physical quantity associated with $\hat Q$ (and of course $\mid\psi_n\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat{Q}$).
There are cases where the eigenvalue and expectation value are the same. An example would be a quantum system where every outcome of the measurement of $\hat Q$ has the same probability.

So the expectation value of an observable $\hat{Q}$, is the average of the values of $q$ that you would expect? This confuses me, as for a given  $\hat{Q}$ and $\mid\psi_n\rangle$, there is only one $q$.

The real difference results from arbitrary or mixed states.
$|\Psi\rangle=\sum c_k|\psi_k\rangle$
$\hat O|\psi_k\rangle=\lambda_k|\psi_k\rangle$
$1=\sum c_kc_k^*$
$\hat O |\Psi\rangle=\sum c_k \hat O|\psi_k\rangle=\sum c_k c_k^* \lambda_k|\psi_k\rangle$
$\langle \Psi|\hat O | \Psi \rangle=\sum c_kc_k^*\lambda_k=\langle \hat O \rangle$
The eigenvalue and the expectation value are the same for a single eigenstate. The relationship is more complicated for more than one state.

Applying an operator to any vector, whether or not it is an eigenvector, returns a vector not an eigenvalue:
$$X|\psi_n\rangle=x_n|\psi_n\rangle\neq x_n.$$
The expectation value of $X$ in the state $|\psi_n\rangle$ is a number and it happens to be the eigenvalue in this state:
$$\langle\psi_n|X|\psi_n\rangle=x_n.$$
For any state $|\phi\rangle=\sum_n\alpha_nx_n$, we have:
$$X|\phi\rangle=\sum_n\alpha_nx_n|\psi_n\rangle$$
which is a vector not a number and
$$\langle\phi|X|\phi\rangle=\sum_n|\alpha_n|^2x_n$$
which is a number but may not be equal to any of the eigenvalues.
The product of a state and an operator gives you the result of performing some operation on the state. For example, the not operator applied to a qubit gives you the result of flipping that qubit.
The numbers $|\alpha_n|^2$ play the roles of probabilities in situations where the state has decohered, which includes many measurements:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.09019

It could conceivably be argued that $\langle \psi | \hat{Q} | \psi \rangle$ has a physical meaning while $\hat{Q} | \psi \rangle$ does not (unless $\hat{Q}$ is a unitary or projector). The first is the average value that occurs when we measure $|\psi\rangle$ an infinite (or near infinite) number of times to determine the value of $Q$ (assuming $\hat{Q}$ is Hermitian). If $0\leq \hat{Q}^{\dagger} \hat{Q} \leq 1$ then we can interpret $\hat{Q}$ as an update and $\hat{Q}|\psi \rangle$ as a different (possibly unnormalised) quantum state. Otherwise, it is only a mathematical intermediary for determining something else. While I wrote this for general pure states $|\psi\rangle$, this is also true for eigenvectors of $\hat{Q}$, $|\psi_{n}\rangle$.
In contrast, $\hat{Q}|\psi_{n}\rangle = q_{n} |\psi_{n}\rangle$ has an interpretation as specifying an eigenvalue and eigenvector pair from $\hat{Q}$. This informs us that the quantity $Q$ is well defined for the state $|\psi_{n}\rangle$ and measurements of $Q$ will not change the state, which may not always be the case.
Or if you prefer a mathematical difference, $\langle \psi |\hat{Q}|\psi\rangle$ is a number, while $\hat{Q}|\psi\rangle$ is a vector. So they are used for different things.
